# getting up and running with require.js and testr.js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dependency-injection, requirejs

I'm having a little trouble getting up and running with using [testr.js](https://github.com/medallia/testr.js) to mock [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) dependencies.  I have the following directory structure:

```
<root>
  |-- Scripts
  |    |-- lib
  |    |    +-- require.js
  |    +-- modules
  |         |-- dependency.js
  |         +-- testable-thing.js
  |-- Test
  |    |-- lib
  |    |    +-- testr.js
  |    +-- index.html
  +-- index.html
```

The system under test in this case will be `testable-thing.js`, and the dependency I want to switch out using testr is `dependency.js`.  Here are there source codes:

```js
// testable-thing.js
define(["scripts/modules/dependency"], function (dep) {
    console.log("testable thing loaded");
});

// dependency.js
define(function () {
    console.log("dependency loaded");
});
```

When requesting `http://<root>/index.html` using the `require-config.js` (source below) this works fine and logs to the console:

[image: image showing require js loading things correctly]

I also have the entry point `http://<root>/test/index.html`, which in a full app will run the JavaScript unit tests.  It looks like this:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="/scripts/lib/require.js"></script>
    <script src="/test/lib/testr.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

        testr.config({
            root: "../"
        });

        testr.run("/scripts/require-config.js", function () {
            console.log("entering tests");

            var sut = testr("modules/testable-thing", {
                "modules/dependency": function () {
                    console.log("stub loaded");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is where I am having trouble.  It gives this output:

[image: image showing module bindings wanging out with testr]

Now, I understand that testr.js overwrites RequireJS's `require` method to register what modules are loaded and overwrite them with the stubs/mocks passed to the `testr` function, but I can't for the life of me workout how to "load" these dependencies.  If I modify `testr.run` callback routine in `test/index.html` to include something that does load dependencies:

```js
testr.run("/scripts/require-config.js", function () {
    console.log("entering tests");

    require(["modules/testable-thing"], function () { });

    var sut = testr("modules/testable-thing", {
        "modules/dependency": function () {
            console.log("stub loaded");
        }
    });
});
```

then this happens:

[image: image showing attempting to load the modules before hand is even stranger]

I am really not sure why `entering tests` is printed twice here.  It only appears in that one place in the source code.

Here is my `<root>/index.html` and my `<root>/scripts/require-config.js`:

```html
// <root>/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="/scripts/lib/require.js" data-main="/scripts/require-config.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
require(["modules/testable-thing"], function (testableThing) {
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
// <root>/scripts/require-config.js

require.config({
    baseUrl: "/scripts"
});
```

How can I get up and running with mocking these dependencies?  When requesting `<root>/test/index.html` I want to see:

```
entering tests
stub loaded
testable thing loaded
```

in Chrome console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had one thing slightly wrong.  In `http://<root>/tests/index.html`:

```
require(["modules/testable-thing"], function () {
    console.log("entering tests");

    var sut = testr("modules/testable-thing", {
        "modules/dependency":  {
            run: function () {
                console.log("stub loaded");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Note how the tests are run as the callback passed to `require()`.  [This article](http://cyberasylum.janithw.com/mocking-requirejs-dependencies-for-unit-testing/) by Boilerplatejs contributor Janith was helpful with this.

In addition, there appears to be a bug in the current version of testr.  Using latest ([1.3.2](http://pastebin.com/vX6hAZJN)) we get this output:

[image]

whereas using [1.0.2](http://pastebin.com/skK9L1px) (which is what Boilerplatejs uses) we get success:

[image]

Going to do some more investigation this evening and see what's up with this.